# How can i insert element inside dom correctly and something about setInterval

Tags: javascript, date, setinterval, clock, clearinterval

i got a task that ask me to create a page, which can display a clock after

the user click on the start button and stop when click the stop button

The clock need to display inside a "span" tag because i need the DOM1 method.

So my Code currently look's like this

*I had already fix this.

```
function clock()
{


var obj = document.getElementById('clock');
if (obj)
{
var now = new Date();
var mytime = now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+"."+now.getSeconds();
obj.innerHTML = mytime;

}
}




</script>

</head>

<body onload="clock()">
<table>
<h1>A live clock in JavaScript</h1>

<p>The time according to your PC is :<span id="clock"></span></p>




<input type="button" name="clickMe" value="Start the clock"
onclick="timer = setInterval(clock, 1000)"/>


<button onclick="window.clearInterval(timer)">Stop</button>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj.document.getElementById('clock');
```

Since `obj` is undefined at this point, it will throw a `referenceError`. Perhaps you meant:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('clock');
```

---

```
if (obj != "false")
```

This will most likely not work, since you're comparing to a string. If you want to check whether `obj` is an object or `null`, you can use

```
if (obj)
```

---

```
obj = mytime;
```

this will not modify the original `obj`, but rather overwrite the variable holding a reference to it. Perhaps you wanted

```
obj.innerHtml = mytime;
```

also change the HTML from

```
<p id="clock">The time according to your PC is :</p>
```

to

```
<p>The time according to your PC is :<span id="clock"></span></p>
```

so that you don't overwrite the text but do overwrite the clock.

---

```
onclick="setTimeout('"
...
onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)"
```

there is a part missing:

```
onclick="timer = setInterval(clock, 1000)"
...
onclick="window.clearInterval(timer)"
```

where the first argument is the function being called repeatedly, and the second argument is the frequency of the calls in miliseconds. Also note that the return value of `clearInterval` is not particularly useful since the argument to it should be the value returned by `setInterval`.

Also note the distinction between `setTimeout` (which will call a function once) and `setInterval` (which will call it repeatedly).

Also note that the `timer` variable now resides in the global scope. This could be a problem in larger projects. You also have a problem if you start the timer several times as you can't stop it now. Consider this instead (at the end of `body`) (and assign the correct IDs to both inputs):

```
(function(){ //create a scope
  var timer; //create a local variable

  document.getElementById("clock-start")
  .addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!timer) timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);
  })

  document.getElementById("clock-stop")
  .addEventListener("click", function(){
    clearInterval(clock);
  })
})() // remember to call our anonymous function
```

or the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) version (anywhere in the document):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //execute on DOM ready
  var timer;

  $("#clock-start").on("click", function(){
    if(!timer) timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);
  })

  $("#clock-stop").on("click", function(){
    clearInterval(clock);
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my questions , but i still have few problem with this. First, my clock never appear on my page and second i don't really understand what is the function you ask me to insert inside my page mean, is that for me to control those buttons? and my teacher haven"t mention about how to call out the anonymous function yet, so how can i do that?

Comment: @AnsonAştepta tell me of them. I thought I caught everything.